# syntastic: include header files that are spread around in a large project

Tags: vim, syntastic

I have a big C project with many software components around. The file tree has a root, say `C:\MyProject\SoftwareComponents\` that contains a bunch of sub-folders which in turn contain some other sub-folders that contain `.c` and `.h` files. A sketch of such a file tree looks like this

```
C:\MyProject\SoftwareComponents\
                                 CompOne\
                                 Foo\
                                 Fii\
                                 ...
                                 Zooroo\
```

I am failing in setting the option `let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs=...` since I always get an error like: `fatal error: xyz.h: No such file or directory`. I tried to tweak Syntastic in many ways like

```
let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs = ['./../inc','./inc'] 
...
```

but this approach seems to heavily depend on `pwd` and it is not robust.

All the solutions that I found suggest to list the all components sub-folders one-by-one in let `g:syntastic_c_include_dirs` where you may possibly have some `.h` file but for my case it is very inefficient as I have way too many software components and listing each folder one-by-one is impossible.

I thought that one may use some wildcard, e.g.   `let g:syntastic_c_include_dirs = ['C:\MyProject\SoftwareComponents\**']` but it does not work.

Comment: The solution is to use a specialized plugin for checking C files, such as YCM.  Syntastic is essentially dead these days anyway.  But if you absolutely must use it, write a config file (cf. `:h syntastic-config-files`), and point `g:syntastic_c_config_file` to it.

Comment: Thanks you! What if I want to do it with YCM?